# What's a one-liner with low computational complexity for returning the two biggest values of an array?

Tags: perl

This is more of a "I am interested if it's possible" than a "I really need it" question, but anyway: I know if I want the smallest value in a list using a custom function comparison, I can do it easily with `List::Util::reduce`.

```
my $biggest = reduce {comparison($a, $b) ? $b:$a} @myArray;
```

But if I want the **two biggest** values in that array? Again, with just one traversal of the array.

I can do it by writing a `for` loop, but I would really like a more perlish one-liner.

---

Edit: By *just one traversal of the array*, I meant that the computational complexity won't be bigger than `O(n)`. Sorting all the articles is not that effective since I don't need *everything* sorted, just the two biggest values.

But I am probably asking too much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the max two values of a list, you can either loop across the values with two variables to hold the maximums:

```
my @list = qw(3 1 2 5 9 7 8 6 4);

my ($x, $y) = (0, 0);

($x, $y) = $_ > $x ? ($_, $x) :
           $_ > $y ? ($x, $_) : next for @list;

say "$x $y";  # '9 8'
```

or you can use a fold to reduce the list:

```
use List::Util 'reduce';

my $max = reduce {
    $b > $$a[0] ? [$b, $$a[0]] : 
    $b > $$a[1] ? [$$a[0], $b] : $a
} [0, 0], @list;

say "@$max"; # '9 8'
```

The two solutions are equivalent, the first is procedural in nature and requires external state, the second is functional and does not.  The first is likely faster since it does not create any internal arrays for storage.  Each only loops over the list once, so both are `O(n)`

Comment: This is nicely done, but the `[0, 0]` to start the fold is problematic. It assumes that there's a least member of the set that `@list` is drawn from, which might not be true. It'd be better to start with the first two elements of `@list` and then `reduce` over the rest, but you need to make sure to put them in the right order so that the invariant holds — and then the whole thing gets pretty unwieldy.

Comment: OK. These one-liners are exactly what I wanted. (And they are also so horribly unreadable that I will really think twice before asking for perl one-liners :))

Answer (score 4):

There's always `(sort { compare($b, $a) } @array)[0 .. 1]` -- which works for any number of outputs you want, as long as you make sure not to try to take more items than exist in `@array`. The downside is that it does more work in sorting the whole array than it really has to.

You can also extend the `reduce` solution to keep any number of largest values seen so far, but I haven't yet been able to write a version of that that still has the "one-liner" feel :)

Comment: sort makes string comparison between elements, so 11 will be smaller than 2

Comment: assuming compare returns -1, 0, or 1; the original example just did true or false

Comment: Yes, but the sort is computationally much more difficult than O(n).

I should have added that to my question too, probably.

Answer (score 1):

```
my @biggest_two = ( sort { $b <=> $a } @myArray )[0..1]
```

Comment: True that, thanks for the edit David and thanks for the observation FMc

Answer (score -1):

I have been thinking about this one for a while. I think logically we can prove it is impossible to do this for a general comparison function `comparison($a,$b)`.

When testing for some simple comparison function, say `>` for example one can use the transitive property that if `a > b` and `b > c` then `a > c`, and therefore one can cascade the search for a greatest value in one pass. If you want to use that to find the two highest values you can do that too, but already you have added complexity. The number being tested may be greater than both OR it may only be greater than one and less than the other OR it may be less than both. Still this may be accounted for as shown in this simple script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @array = shuffle (1..10);
my @out = (0,0); #(max, second)

map { $_>$out[0] ? ( unshift @out, $_ and pop @out) : $_>$out[1] ? $out[1] = $_ : () } @array;

print "$_\n" for @out;
```

For a truly generic comparison one must consider the possibility that the combination of the two values being compared matters in which case every pairwise combination must be taken. In fact this IS implicitly done above, however most of the tests are skipped because by the transitive property we know that it is safe to do so.

So there you have it. If your test has a transitive relationship, you may do something like what I do above. If not then `sort` will have to do. The Perl guys spend a lot of time making it fast, so perhaps its not too bad.